# rtabmap_ros loop closure rejection when doing tutorial

Tags: slam, navigation, stere-image-proc, rtabmap, rtabmap-ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using **ros indigo** in **ubuntu 14.04** when i am running the stereo outdoor tutorial in `rtabmap_ros` with `Stereo_outdoorB.bag` file as in :[link](http://wiki.ros.org/rtabmap_ros/Tutorials/StereoOutdoorMapping) i get a `loop closure rejction` error at the end of the bagfile

here I have atached the screenshots :
[image: image description]

[image: image description]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/227661/rtabmap_ros-loop-closure-rejection-when-doing-tutorial/) by [Azharudeen](https://answers.ros.org/users/23697/azharudeen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 90 on 2016-02-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

Use the updated [demo_stereo_outdoor.launch](https://github.com/introlab/rtabmap_ros/blob/master/launch/demo/demo_stereo_outdoor.launch) from 0.10.12, not the one installed by 0.10.10. Just download the launch file, you would not need to rebuild rtabmap from source.

The old launch file is broken because of the new `RGBD/OptimizeMaxError` parameter. Either set `RGBD/OptimizeMaxError` to 0 under the rtabmap node or use the launch file above.

cheers

---

Originally posted by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) with karma: 6409 on 2016-02-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Azharudeen](https://answers.ros.org/users/23697/azharudeen/) on 2016-03-03**:
thanks matlabbe

**Comment by [Azharudeen](https://answers.ros.org/users/23697/azharudeen/) on 2016-03-03**:
The loop closure error was solved but now i get this error: `updateMapCloud() map id of node X not found` as in the picture i have posted

**Comment by [Azharudeen](https://answers.ros.org/users/23697/azharudeen/) on 2016-03-04**:
thanks for your suggestion on new version i rebuild the entire package after downloading the new version it worked...... thanks